# What is the right way to display the KPI number?

Tags: data, dashboard, numbers

I'm designing a dashboard, and one of the cards should display the status of the activated users - if there's any problem - it's should emphasize that and show how many users are not activated.

[image]

The problem that I have in (1) is that the neutral state and the "problematic" state both show a positive number and change between "activated" to "not activated", my concern it's that the user can be confused.

In (2) I tried to fix it, but I don't really think it's a good solution - the user needs to calculate how many are not activated.

Which solution works best in your opinion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could show a breakup of user status below the total number of users and that way you can easily find out if there is any user that needs to be activated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sooraj MV, I appreciate it! 

You don't think it's problematic data-wise to keep the "not activated" displayed all the time? (the users should always be activated by default and only by a bug the user becomes not activated)

Comment: It should be fine, but If you think it's redundant, you can use your grey circle design as default.